# module parse failed error while importing css file in react with next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a react project with using next.js. I want to import some css files into my file like bootstrap or font-awesome. But it fails when I try to start server.

Here is the error:
Failed to compile
./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

I looked some solutions and some says there is a problem with importing way. But I tried the both following but the result is same.

import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import css from'../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

Most of the solutions say about the css-loader of webpack and change the config file. I have already tried it also. I've installed this npm install --save-dev css-loader and changed my config file but the problem hasn't changed.

Here my next.config.js file:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({

  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({

      test: /\.md$/,
      use: "raw-loader",

    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    }

    );
    return config;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `css-loader`, remove this part:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}
```

`withCss` next plugin configures all related to css imports.
The error tells specifically that it can't handle **ttf** files.

Use [`next-fonts`](https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts) to configure fonts loaders.

```
https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts
```

```
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
module.exports = withFonts({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config;
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but the problem does not solve. I guess next.js has problem with css loader.

Comment: Next added native support for css modules at version 9.2 , try it.